# How to determine PCIe slot number from dmesg error message?

Tags: linux, pci-e

I have a Linux system that contains several PCIe cards.  dmesg indicates that one of the cards is generating an error:

```
[ 3970.385387] pcieport 0000:00:02.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, id=0010(Transmitter ID)
[ 3970.385389] pcieport 0000:00:02.0:   device [8086:2f04] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[ 3970.385391] pcieport 0000:00:02.0:    [12] Replay Timer Timeout
```

How can I determine the slot number from [8086:2f04] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to find information about all slots in the system.

```
dmidecode -t slot
```

> How can I determine the slot number from [8086:2f04] ?

You can use `lspci` for that, more specifically `lspci -nv`.
Once you know specifically you can use `lspci -s <slot number>` to investigate further.

Comment: Thanks. So that gives: 80:02.0 0604: 8086:2f04 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) How can I get the slot number from this please?

Comment: Added more details for you, please see revised answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help.